# Combine SQL cell output in a markdown cell in Databricks Notebook

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I would like to run a cell in SQL and then include a markdown cells that includes the cell output.

**SQL cell :** select count(*) from table

1500

1 row returned

**Expected Output:**
Markdown cell : Row count of the table is **1500**

Comment: Can you provide how your expected output should be? Is the current markdown cell should hold the previous SQL cell output?

Comment: Yes, previous cell output @RakeshGovindula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [ask](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/is-it-possible-to-access-a-variable-in-markdown-cells/td-p/13565), currently markdown cells don't support variables, or we can't pass any cell's output dynamically to the markdown cell. It's still a feature request.

As an alternative, you can try the below workaround where a python cell is used to generate the expected markdown result.

Give your SQL count code in the `spark.sql()` and get the required markdown like below.

```
%python

from IPython.display import display, Markdown
count = spark.sql('select  count(*) from table1').select("*").first()[0]
display(Markdown('## Row count of the table is '+str(count)))
```

[image]

**NOTE**: If it doesn't work, make sure the Databricks runtime is latest. Here, my runtime is `13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)`